# Login screen is disfigured

Tags: ati, xorg, 14.04, unity-greeter

This is the second time I see it this way when I startup my machine. You can see that the screen is not fully utilized. Ubuntu's screen starts from the top-left, but doesn't fill the whole screen. The underutilized area isn't totally black. But it's a mauve background with white dots all over it, I think it's the stock background for the login screen but I'm not sure. This doesn't happen when I lock my screen.

[image]

What is causing this and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems maybe someone activated some zoom option of the "Universal Access Preferences" available in the lower left part or lower right of the GDM login screen that transforms the left part of the screen in a magnifier lens.

You can try setting it up such that it doesn't start on login using:

```
sudo -u gdm gconftool-2 /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_magnifier_enabled --type bool --set false
```

or purging that package (not recommended) using:

```
sudo aptitude purge gnome-mag
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1545815

Comment: Sorry, but GDM has been replaced by LightDM long ago and the `gnome-mag` package doesn't seem to exist on 14.04 either.